# put routing values in @HtmlActionLink with parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Link, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.ActionLink("View", "Viewer", "Drawings", new { filePath = ....... }, new { target="_blank"})
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm new to mvc, here the @model.Link has the file name, my confusion is how to put model values in filePath, it it were a reqular text box I would have done this way @Html.textboxFor(model=> model.Link). But I cannot do lamba expression getting an error.

Comment: `new { filePath = Model.Link }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Below  oveload of an Actionlink will be helpful for you

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

**Your Example:**

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Link, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.ActionLink("View", "Viewer", "Drawings", new { filePath = Model.Link ,filename = Model.fileName ,...etc }, new { target="_blank"})
            </div>
        </div>
```

And  your controller action method will look like to get the value:

```
public class ViewerController:Controller
{

   public ActionResult view(string filepath,string filename) //datatype may vary according to the model
    {
          //your action logic

     }

}
```